# How to convert from a string array to a char array array?

Tags: c++, linux, exec

I want to pass an array of arguments to exec() function. The current parameters are all strings. How could I convert the array of string into the array of char array?

Right now I'm using const_cast to remove the const. The code does not look nice.
Is there a better solution?

Sample code looks like:

```
void f(const string &dev, const string &status){

  char* args[] = {"link", "set", "dev", const_cast<char*>(dev.c_str()), 
  const_cast<char*>(status.c_str())};
  execv("/sbin/ip", args);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add const in the type iso casting it away?

Comment: `char* arg0 = "link"` should also be problematic, as `const` (or cast here) is missing too...

Comment: I am not sure, but will the lifetimes of `dev` and `status` matter here?  You're calling `execv` and populating it with strings returned by `std::string`'s that go out of scope after `main` exits.

Comment: Can you take parameter by value, instead of const ref? (a way to remove `const`, and if copy would have be done in function (as suggested in answer, it might avoid an extra copy)).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to declare `args` as an array of `char const*`:

```
char const* args[] = {"link", "set", "dev", dev.c_str(), status.c_str()};
```

However, if you truly need a `char*` and not a `char const*`, as `execv` requires, we need [`std::string::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data):

```
void f(const string &dev_, const string &status_){
  // Note: string literals don't convert to char* in C++,
  // although some compilers allow it as an extension.

  // Declare these as arrays so we can form `char*`s to them:
  char link[] = "link";
  char set[] = "set";
  char dev_lit[] = "dev";

  // No choice but to copy the const args:
  std::string dev{dev_};
  std::string status{status_};

  // C++17-specific:
  char* args[] = {link, set, dev_lit, dev.data(), status.data()};
  execv("/sbin/ip", args);
}
```

Before C++17, you can use `&status[0]` rather than `status.data()`, which is correct even if `status.size() == 0`.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that `execv` is taking `char *const`. If I'm passing `char const*`, it will throw error `invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’`.

Comment: @stcheng Yeah, that's why I also gave how to get `char*`s instead of `char const*`s.

Comment: just updated my question, the two strings are also const :(

Comment: As you copy arguments, taking them by copy might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> The code does not look nice. Is there a better solution?

For what it's worth, use of

```
char* args[] = {"link", "set", "dev", ... };
```

is wrong to start with. String literals can decay to `char const*`, not `char*`.

I suggest use of a helper function that uses `strdup` to give you a copy of the input string.

```
char* toArg(std::string const& s)
{
    return strdup(s.c_str());
}
```

and use

```
char* args[] = {toArg("link"), toArg("set"), toArg("dev"), toArg(dev), toArg(status)};
```

Comment: BTW, `"link"` is still not a `char*`.

Comment: @Jarod42, true.

Comment: This is C++, not C. Don't use `strdup`, use a `std::string` copy. Besides, heap-allocating memory for the string literals is wasteful.